# PUT file data to a Autodesk API with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, autodesk-forge

I am following the process described [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) but getting stopped by a `403` at Step 4. I have a token with `data:write` and `data:create` scopes as [specified in the docs](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/) (and other API methods needing those scopes work) but I can't get a successful response and I think it's down to how I am sending the file data. My code looks like this:

```
url = '{}oss/v2/buckets/{}/objects/{}'.format(self.DOMAIN, bucket_id, object_name)
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
response = self.session.put(url, data=file_content, headers={
    'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
}
```

The auth token is already included in the session's headers. Here are the logs from the upload process:

```
INFO Creating storage for README.md file in Test Project project, folder urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
INFO Storage success, start PUT file to https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:wip.dm.prod/objects/eb0e0379-9958-45b5-8bb0-5f4111b7a037.md
WARNING Upload failed, status 403: {"developerMessage":"ACM check failed, user or calling service does not have access to perform this operation","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-012","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-012"}
```

Comment: Hard to tell based on such a thin description... can you show the bucket_id and objet_name? Are they correct? You can only upload a single resource to a given storage created at step 3. Also the error response should contain metadata in addition to the http code that may give a hint

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma yes, the info is correct, the bucket and object info is working in the previous step. The metadata simply tells me I have a permission problem which seems misleading given the prior step (and every other bit I am doing) works with the same token's scopes.

Comment: I've added the logs of what I get back and need to correct my last comment: I don't know if the bucket id is correct based on the prior storage request, so I will focus on finding that out. The bucket id in my log above seems relatively short compared to other ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a sample code with Python in the past with v1 endpoints. I migrated to v2 today. It looks working well. Could you take a look if it could help you to address the issue you are having? 
https://github.com/xiaodongliang/forge.workflow-python-sample

Comment: Thanks for the code, it looks pretty much the same as mine though. Can you tell from the logs I've added what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks, that moved me along as it turned out I needed to check if the bucket exists, which isn't listed [between steps 3 and 4 here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) and I wasn't stripping the `:` off my bucket id.