# Create File Version with Autodesk API

Tags: python, autodesk-forge

Following on from my [file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699226/put-file-data-to-a-autodesk-api-with-python-requests/46708242#46708242) question, I am getting stuck at [Step 5](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) in the documentation. I get a 400 error suggesting some of the data I am sending is incorrect, but I think I have matched the code exactly.

```
def create_version_for_file(self, file_name, project_id, folder_id, object_id):
    url = '{}data/v1/projects/{}/items'.format(self.DOMAIN, project_id)
    logger.info('Starting version create at %s for file_name %s, folder %s, object %s',
                url, file_name, folder_id, object_id)
    data = {
        "jsonapi": {"version": "1.0"},
        "data": {
            "type": "items",
            "attributes": {
                "displayName": file_name,
                "extension": {
                    "type": "items:autodesk.core:File",
                    "version": "1.0"
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "tip": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "versions",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                },
                "parent": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "folders",
                        "id": folder_id
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "included": [
            {
                "type": "versions",
                "id": "1",
                "attributes": {
                    "name": file_name,
                    "extension": {
                        "type": "versions:autodesk.core:File",
                        "version": "1.0"
                    }
                },
                "relationships": {
                    "storage": {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "objects",
                            "id": object_id
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    response = self.session.post(url, json=data, headers={
        'content-type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
        'accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'
    })
    if response.status_code != status.HTTP_201_CREATED:
        logger.warn('Version create for %s failed with status %s: %s', file_name, response.status_code,
                    response.content)
        return None
    return json.loads(response.content)
```

However, the request always fails like so:

```
Upload succeeded for README.md 2017-10-12 16:53:15,943 
Starting version create at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.f19577f2-c4da-428f-9625-bb53bf434cca/items for file_name README.md, folder urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.Hx1ePxPtS1e0P-Ib9qudyQ, object urn:adsk.objects:os.object:3a06e38e-4cac-4ffc-981f-0e5c4e4078aab.f19577f2-c4da-428f-9625-bb53bf434cca/d14c3591-d339-4e62-907c-6f0c8b58b743.md
Version create for README.md failed with status 400: {"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"bfbf0a93-c92a-47af-9ce7-a6af48594e44","status":"400","code":"BAD_INPUT","title":"One or more input values in the request were bad","detail":"Request input is invalid for this operation."}]}
```

Sample values for all of the variables are off to the right in the logs above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be setup correctly but maybe you have your storage location created in the incorrect folder. From the tutorial I suggested in the forum post, you need to navigate down one level to avoid the creation of the storage location on the Root folder of BIM 360 Docs. Try going back on your steps and do the followed suggested on the tutorial. Focus on step number 4

1. Authorization Web Flow (This will return us the code we need to obtain our oauth token)
2. Rest call to the Authentication API to obtain a 3 legged Token GET call to obtain detail of which Hubs do we have access in BIM 360 Docs (Registration of APP required for BIM 360 API access)
3. GET call to find the project that has your resource
4. GET call to find the folder where the upload will happen (Plans, Project File, Drawings).

   4.1 Extra step can include the access to a sub-folder.
5. POST call to create a storage location in the previously defined folder
6. PUT call to upload file to the storage location
7. POST call to create the first version of the uploaded file.

Check BIM 360 Docs to see your recently uploaded file.

Comment: Thanks, but that tutorial is confusing me at step 5-6: in 5 you make a storage location for an `.rvt` file but show a response with an object id for a PDF file of `633fc6c2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3db6e54d7ef4.pdf` which does not match the data posted in the step 6 example where you send `acecf083-a567-4cef-9873-d2842e52c725.rvt` as the object id. I'm guessing the response in the middle with the PDF is wrong?

Comment: Well, either way, that example got me home, so thanks. Your link is much better than the canonical tutorial, there are a couple of errors in that which sent me down the wrong road.

Comment: Oh yes it is incorrect, I will fix this thanks for finding this. Glad you are good to go now man. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. When you get a chance, can you take a look at my [next stopping point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793868/update-file-version-with-autodesk-api)? It seems to be a doc error as well.

Comment: I'll try to get to it later on today. I took it already in our queue :)

Comment: If you land here, make sure you look at @Tom 's point. I searched for a while!

Answer (score 1):

From this [forum response](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-api-forum/question-about-data-management-api/td-p/7360830), [the tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) is out-of-date and you should use `autodesk.bim360:File` (but not `autodedsk.bim360:File` as the typo suggests) in place of `autodesk.core:File`. There is a more recent [example here.](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/tutorial-using-curl-3-legged-authentication-bim-360-docs-upload).

It's still not working but at least my error moved on to `The urn must be an unassigned urn prepared by the create storage endpoint, by the same user.`

Comment: This error means you are passing an incorrect storage location, first you need to call the POST projects/:project_id/storage endpoint, obtain a new storage for each version of a file that you upload and provide the correct objectId of the storage to the payload. I have complete node.js code there as an example: http://autode.sk/2yp2rVj