# Update File Version with Autodesk API

Tags: python, autodesk-forge

I am now able to [upload a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699226/put-file-data-to-a-autodesk-api-with-python-requests) and create an [initial version for the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718771/create-file-version-with-autodesk-api) but am unable to update the version. Using the code in [Step 6 of this tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) does not work even after replacing `versions:autodesk.core:File` with `versions:autodesk.bim360:File`. From the error message, `Request contains 0 includes instead of 1`, it seems I need part of the `included` block from the example in Step 5 but I am not sure what it should look like; given the outer `relationships` blocks do not match in format between Steps 5 and 6, I am assuming the inner content varies as well.

```
def create_version_for_file(self, project_name, file_name, folder_id, object_id, storage_id):
    project_id = self.get_project_id_by_name(project_name)
    existing_object_id = self.get_version_id_for_file_in_folder(project_name, folder_id, file_name)
    url = '{}data/v1/projects/{}/items'.format(self.DOMAIN, project_id)
    logger.info('Starting version create at %s for file_name %s, folder %s, object %s',
                url, file_name, folder_id, object_id)
    if existing_object_id:
        logger.info('Creating version for existing object')
        data = self._get_version_data_for_existing_file(file_name, object_id, storage_id)
    else:
        logger.info('Creating version for new object')
        data = self._get_version_json_for_new_file(file_name, folder_id, object_id)
    response = self.session.post(url, json=data, headers={
        'content-type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
        'accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'
    })
    if response.status_code != status.HTTP_201_CREATED:
        logger.warn('Version create for %s failed with status %s: %s', file_name, response.status_code,
                    response.content)
        return None
    return json.loads(response.content)

def _get_version_json_for_new_file(self, file_name, folder_id, object_id):
    return {
        "jsonapi": {"version": "1.0"},
        "data": {
            "type": "items",
            "attributes": {
                "displayName": file_name,
                "extension": {
                    "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
                    "version": "1.0"
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "tip": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "versions",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                },
                "parent": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "folders",
                        "id": folder_id
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "included": [
            {
                "type": "versions",
                "id": "1",
                "attributes": {
                    "name": file_name,
                    "extension": {
                        "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
                        "version": "1.0"
                    }
                },
                "relationships": {
                    "storage": {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "objects",
                            "id": object_id
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

def _get_version_data_for_existing_file(self, file_name, object_id, storage_id):
    return {
        "jsonapi": {
            "version": "1.0"
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "versions",
            "attributes": {
                "name": file_name,
                "extension": {
                    "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
                    "version": "1.0"
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "item": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "items",
                        "id": object_id
                    }
                },
                "storage": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "objects",
                        "id": storage_id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your payloads are correct. To create the second version, you have to send your request to the [CreateVersion endpoint](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/).

```
    url = '{}data/v1/projects/{}/versions'.format(self.DOMAIN, project_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing a little detail that makes it not working, but since you provide so little description nobody can tell based on that ... In order to create a new version, you first need to create a new storage location, upload the file to that location, and post a new version, referencing the existing item id.

Alternatively take a look my that node js sample to [upload a file and create a new item or version](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/server/api/endpoints/dm.js#L367) if the item exists.

Comment: Added the code. I don't think I am missing a small detail: I am copying the code directly from the example for the create first version and add additional version examples and the second example's JSON seems to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The data for your updating the version seems incorrect to me, Try the following steps.

- Create a new Storage location on the same folder where V1 of your file is located
- upload v2 of your file to the new storage location created on the step below.
- Get the item ID of the resource from the manifest result of your successful upload of V1 or call the following end point to obtain the ID https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET
- Once you have all this information your data to pass in will look like this.

  ```
  {
  "jsonapi": { "version": "1.0" },
  "data": {
    "type": "versions",
    "attributes": {
       "name": "v2File.rvt",
       "extension": { "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File", "version": "1.0"}
    },
    "relationships": {
       "item": { "data": { "type": "items", "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:8jehs1iSQGu_wXpZ977bjA" } },
       "storage": { "data": { "type": "objects", "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/a7fde689-62cf-49c1-9273-8df976568996.rvt" } }
    }
   }
  }
  ```

The only difference I can think of is your objectId is not correct. Image below is proof of both versions uploaded with the API.

[image]

Comment: I think I am confused then. Is the key modifying the name to include the `v2` in front of it to indicate the version? I've been passing the same filename `attributes.name`) each time assuming the versioning would happen via some other key.

Comment: Added a tutorial https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/update-bim360-docs-file-version-insomnia-rest-and-data-management-api